# VBA Collection - Passing a variable as a key

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write code that returns the name of the current month in French. I have created a collection, and it does return my month, but I cannot connect it to the second function that returns the number of the current month.

The first and second MsgBox return DECEMBRE and "12" as expected, but the last one returns the runtime error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument.

```
Sub test()

    Dim Month1 As String
    Dim dict As New Collection

    dict.Add "JANVIER", "1"
    dict.Add "FÉVRIER", "2"
    dict.Add "MARS", "3"
    dict.Add "AVRIL", "4"
    dict.Add "MAI", "5"
    dict.Add "JUIN", "6"
    dict.Add "JUILLET", "7"
    dict.Add "AOUT", "8"
    dict.Add "SEPTEMBRE", "9"
    dict.Add "OCTOBRE", "10"
    dict.Add "NOVEMBRE", "11"
    dict.Add "DÉCEMBRE", "12"

    Month1 = """" & Month(Now) & """"
    MsgBox (dict.Item("12"))     '1st check - OK
    MsgBox (Month1)              '2nd check - OK
    MsgBox (dict.Item(Month1))   'final result - FAIL

End Sub
```

Where is the mistake?

Comment: Why are you going to extra lengths to store the quotes inside `Month1`? Quotes are for string literals, the key is `12` (a string, not number 12), not `"12"` with quotes.

Comment: Watch out for extraneous parentheses: `(dict.Item(Month1))` is getting evaluated as an expression, then the result is passed by value as the first argument to `MsgBox` - you would run into compile-time issues if you tried to pass a second argument to the function, because `(expression, expression)` isn't an expression that can be evaluated and whose result can be passed by value as the first argument to `MsgBox`. In other words, do `MsgBox dict.Item(Month1)` instead of `MsgBox (dict.Item(Month1))`, and in general avoid extraneous parentheses in procedure calls.

Comment: GSerg thank you, you have opened my eyes :) I have ignored the type of the variable. As someone mentioned, it's always good to have Locals window open, I was not aware that it's possible, it's a great tool and saves me a lot of concerns. Thank you Mathieu, I have corrected the code. You are right, it's a trap :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"""" & Month(Now) & """"` is wrapping the value in double quotes where `"1"` is just converting the number 1 into a string.   A VBA collection doesn't even care if a number in numeric  or if it is a String.  Both `Month1 =  Month(Now)` and `MsgBox dict.Item(Month(Now))` work.

That being said I would just use an array.

```
Function getMois(MonthIndex As Long) As String
    getMois = Array("JANVIER", "FÉVRIER", "MARS", "AVRIL", "MAI", "JUIN", "JUILLET", "AOUT", "SEPTEMBRE", "OCTOBRE", "NOVEMBRE", "DÉCEMBRE")(MonthIndex - 1)
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you TinMan!
Yes you are completely right, I have tried to give the dict.Item argument that looks exactly the same, but has a wrong type.
I will learn more about the arrays as well, it's obviously much more simple than my solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use just:

```
Month1 = "" & Month(Now)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Function GetMonth(iMonth%)
    GetMonth = Choose(iMonth, "JANVIER", ..., "DÉCEMBRE")
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your code a bit to separate concerns and simply used Excel's implicit conversion to get the Month(Now) as a string. VBA will simply coerce the value into a string, but you could also use type conversion to convert numbers to strings using CSTR().

Overall, some of the other solutions are compact, and you should use them, but it does point out that you might need to become more aware of separation of concerns (essentially, good code habits), type conversions, and implicit/explicit conversion in VBA. Also, you might find it easier to use Debug.Print when coding/debugging, as well as using the Immediate and Locals windows to understand your code.

Code

```
Private dict As Collection
Sub SetArray()

    Set dict = New Collection

    dict.Add "JANVIER", "1"
    dict.Add "FÉVRIER", "2"
    dict.Add "MARS", "3"
    dict.Add "AVRIL", "4"
    dict.Add "MAI", "5"
    dict.Add "JUIN", "6"
    dict.Add "JUILLET", "7"
    dict.Add "AOUT", "8"
    dict.Add "SEPTEMBRE", "9"
    dict.Add "OCTOBRE", "10"
    dict.Add "NOVEMBRE", "11"
    dict.Add "DÉCEMBRE", "12"

End Sub
```

The tests:

```
Sub Test()

    SetArray

    Dim Month1 As String

    Debug.Print dict.Item("12")     '1st check - OK

    Month1 = Month(Now)
    Debug.Print Month1               '2nd check - OK

    Debug.Print dict.Item(Month1)   'final result - SUCCEED

    Month1 = CStr(Month(Now))
    Debug.Print dict.Item(Month1)   'final result - SUCCEED

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you James,
I have learned more about debugging options and found the Locals window which from now will assist me everywhere, it's just what I was looking for :) It helped me to find the solution on my own. Works!